# NextJS custom 404 page not showing up

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a custom `pages/404.ts` with the following content:

```
export default function NotFound() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
}
```

And I have another page that shows 404 when some organization is null:

```
import Error from 'next/error'

const Slug: NextPage<SlugProps> = ({ organization }) => {
  if (!organization) {
    return <Error statusCode={404} />
  }

  return <h1>{organization.name}</h1>
}
```

I want to NextJS show **my** custom 404 page, instead of, it showing the default

[image]

What I need to do to show **my** 404 page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are [reusing the built-in error page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#reusing-the-built-in-error-page).

If you want to display your custom 404 in the dynamic route, just import your `NotFound` component and return that instead.